# Mysql Update columns from same table columns

Tags: mysql, update

I have a table where payments are located with `invoice_id` and `payment_id` and also `payment_due_date` => payment receiving date and `period_months` that is total period of the payment

I have added 2 columns in this table named `service_start_date` and `service_end_date`. I want to update these columns. `service_start_date` will be the first payment date and `service_end_date` will be payment_due_date+period_months. Then next `service_start_date` will be `(payment_due_date+period_months)+1` day and its `service_end`_date will be `service_start_date+period_month` and so on for the next payments.

here is the queries to implement

```
CREATE TABLE `temp_table` (
    `invoice_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
    `payment_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `payment_due_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
    `period_months` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
    `service_start_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
    `service_end_date` date DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
;

insert into `temp_table`
    (`invoice_id`,     `payment_id`,     `payment_due_date`,     `period_months`,     `service_start_date`,     `service_end_date`)
values 
('2065','3337','2015-12-15 00:00:00','3',null,null),  -- '' is not a valid date
('2065','3338','2016-03-14 00:00:00','3',null,null),
('2065','3339','2016-06-12 00:00:00','3',null,null),
('2065','3340','2016-09-10 00:00:00','3',null,null);
```

`select * from temp_table` returns this:

[image]

What I want is this:

[image]

Note: There are multiple invoices in this table and there are multiple payments for each table. I need this to be solve in one single query.

If you have further questions and queries, then please comment.

How can I do this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9079617/update-multiple-columns-in-sql does this help?

Comment: Which version of MySQL is the question about?

Answer (score 1):

I think that you want something like the following:

### BEFORE:

('' is not a valid date - used null instead)

```
mysql> select * from temp_table;
+------------+------------+---------------------+---------------+--------------------+------------------+
| invoice_id | payment_id | payment_due_date    | period_months | service_start_date | service_end_date |
+------------+------------+---------------------+---------------+--------------------+------------------+
|       2065 |       3337 | 2015-12-15 00:00:00 | 3             | NULL               | NULL             |
|       2065 |       3338 | 2016-03-14 00:00:00 | 3             | NULL               | NULL             |
|       2065 |       3339 | 2016-06-12 00:00:00 | 3             | NULL               | NULL             |
|       2065 |       3340 | 2016-09-10 00:00:00 | 3             | NULL               | NULL             |
+------------+------------+---------------------+---------------+--------------------+------------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
mysql>
```

### UPDATE QUERY:

```
UPDATE temp_table
SET 
service_start_date = date(payment_due_date), 
service_end_date = date(payment_due_date) + interval 3 month;
Query OK, 4 rows affected (0.10 sec)
Rows matched: 4  Changed: 4  Warnings: 0
```

### And the result:

(I'm assuming that the service end_date is always 3 months after the payment_due_date).

```
mysql> select * from temp_table;
+------------+------------+---------------------+---------------+--------------------+------------------+
| invoice_id | payment_id | payment_due_date    | period_months | service_start_date | service_end_date |
+------------+------------+---------------------+---------------+--------------------+------------------+
|       2065 |       3337 | 2015-12-15 00:00:00 | 3             | 2015-12-15         | 2016-03-15       |
|       2065 |       3338 | 2016-03-14 00:00:00 | 3             | 2016-03-14         | 2016-06-14       |
|       2065 |       3339 | 2016-06-12 00:00:00 | 3             | 2016-06-12         | 2016-09-12       |
|       2065 |       3340 | 2016-09-10 00:00:00 | 3             | 2016-09-10         | 2016-12-10       |
+------------+------------+---------------------+---------------+--------------------+------------------+
4 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

mysql>

[EDIT - in response to the OP's comments]

We need clearer explanations - clear input data, clear output data and (**perhaps most importantly**) the logic you use to get your derived data.

If you have complicated logic involved in the updates, you might consider using `TRIGGER`s - these can have a complex programming logic behind them. It is always better to perform data manipulation operations as close as possible to the data and as soon as possilbe - apart from direct SQL, nothing is closer or can be performed sooner.

You might also like to consider [`GENERATED` colums](http://mysqlserverteam.com/generated-columns-in-mysql-5-7-5/) (also known as `COMPUTED` and/or `CALCULATED` colums/fields - depending on your RDBMS). These can be `VIRTUAL` (i.e. calculated on the fly) or `STORED` (i.e. actually written to disk) - again, better than code external to the database and faster and more reliable.

The point is, if it's done in and controlled by the database server, **all** applications touching the database will work correctly for that particular field/values - whereas if you implement logic in your application, every application that touches that database will have to re-implement it (and require testing/debugging again and again). Since data tends to be far longer lived than IDEs/app development frameworks, it is **vastly** preferable to keep logic in the RDBMS rather than in developers' heads!

Comment: No this is not the result that i want,
may be i did not explained well. service end_date is not always 3 months it can vary. It may be 2 3 4.... 
and the second problem is for payment_id 3337 it will be simple you made right dates but for next row that is 3338 it will be 1 day add in  service end of 3337. Then 3338 service_start_date will be 2016-03-16

Comment: Is the `period_months` the data we need to determine the gap between `service_start_date` and `service_end_date`? That information will have to be stored somewhere - either in the same table or elsewhere. SQL can't make guesses :-). You say `It may be 2 3 4....` - how can I know? We need clearer explanations - clear input data, clear output data and (perhaps **most importantly**) the logic you use to get your derived data.

Comment: Another thought just came to me. If you use MySQL 5.7, you can use computed fields - [they may help](http://mysqlserverteam.com/generated-columns-in-mysql-5-7-5/)? Also, if you're not using 5.7, have you considered `TRIGGER`s?

Comment: Yes this is sure now this can not be done with one simple query i have involved PHP here.

Comment: @SalmanShahid of course it can be done in a single query.